# How to distinguish the spoken language and written language?

Tags: speech

Today I was confused about the word, 'via'
I have seen this word in many texts, but I have not heard in oral communication.
I tried to search the word 'via' is used in spoken language, but I am not sure yet.

Is there any good way to distinguish the words are for the spoken language or written language? such as if I put a word on a website, the website shows me that the word is used in spoken or written language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Do you mean that there are some words or phrases that are in general not used in written language? Even those  words are written when expressing dialogue or writing in an informal style. The term for such works is “colloquial” or “slang.” A dictionary will indicate that. Words that express utterances that are not really words, for example “Eek!” Or “Oops!” may also count. FWIW, “via” is a legitimate word that can be used in formal writing.

Comment: I've heard "via" spoken numerous times when someone was describing a travel route.  Though "by way of" is probably the more common spoken term.

Comment: (And not sure how you'd search for a word in "spoken language" on the Internet.)

Comment: On my comment- I see that you are asking about words that are only written but not spoken. “Via” is spoken.  I cannot think of any word in English that is only written, except for some obscure technical terms.

Comment: @Damila Well, traditionally, the abbreviations *i.e.* and *e.g.* are not spoken; when reading a text out loud, *i.e.* is replaced with "that is" and *e.g.* is replaced with "for example."

Comment: Good point, @TannerSwett though those are not really words. Nor are they abbreviations for English words. I think I have heard people say ”eye-ee,” but maybe they were being intentionally affected. Good point nevertheless.

Comment: My evening train home is signed at Waterloo as "Guildford via Cobham" and that's what the PA lady says too. 'Via' rhyming with fire, higher, sire, etc.

Comment: I would say the _via_ in _via dolorosa_ to rhyme with 'we are' however.

Comment: Thank you all, I have not had many chances to hear via in conversation, but now I could know via is very common in spoken language.

Comment: Although you said all words except abbreviations in written language could be used in spoken language, the words such as 'therefore', 'nonetheless' are not common in spoken language, aren't they?

Comment: 'Therefore' is very common indeed, and 'nonetheless' not so much, but still not rare. These words are not often found in street talk and teen chat or social media, or American movies or TV shows,  but they are definitely used.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any good way to distinguish the words are for the spoken language or written language?

For the most part, every word that's used in written English is used in spoken English, and vice versa. If you see it in writing, then you can use it in speech, too, and vice versa.

The only exceptions I can think of are certain pieces of Internet slang which were created as abbreviations or emoticons rather than as words. Examples of this are "rofl" (an abbreviation of "rolling on the floor laughing") and "owo" (an emoticon; the "o"s are eyes and the "w" is a cat-like mouth). Although "rofl" and "owo" are common in colloquial Internet writing, they are extremely rare in speech.

Also, certain written words are used mostly for representing speech. For example, consider the following two written questions:

- What do you want to do?
- Whaddya wanna do?

The first version is the normal, common way to write this question. The second version is a special, unusual way of writing the question which indicates a fluent, relaxed way of pronouncing the question out loud.

The *pronunciation* indicated by writing "Whaddya wanna do?" is very common, but actually *writing* it that way is much less common.

Comment: Although you said all words except abbreviations in written language could be used in spoken language, the words such as 'therefore', 'nonetheless' are not common in spoken language, aren't they?

Comment: @PhilipLEE Well, that's true. The words "therefore" and "nonetheless" sound somewhat literary; they're more common in writing than in speech, I think. But they're still reasonably common in speech.